# Error while copying content from one sheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to concatenate sheet `CurrentDistribution` with the sheet `distribution1`. To do that I look at the last row of `distribution1` and copy the content of `CurrentDistribution` after that last row.

```
LastCellCurrentDistribution = FindLastCell(CurrentDistribution)
LastCellDistribution1 = FindLastCell("distribution1")
LastRowInDistribution1 = Right(LastCellDistribution1, Len(LastCellDistribution1) - 1)
Sheets(CurrentDistribution).Range("A4:" + LastCellCurrentDistribution).Copy Sheets("distribution1").Range("A" + CStr((CInt(LastRowInDistribution1) + 1))) 'i only wany the row (number), not the column (letter)
Sheets(CurrentDistribution).Delete
```

Now the problem is that I get this error when I try to do so: `'Run-time error '6': Overflow'`. I used the debugger and found out its the 4th line which copies stuff that is throwing this error. Any idea whats the problem and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like my worksheet is so big that INT type can't handle my last cell number. So replace:

```
Sheets(CurrentDistribution).Range("A4:" + LastCellCurrentDistribution).Copy Sheets("distribution1").Range("A" + CStr((CInt(LastRowInDistribution1) + 1))) 'i only wany the row (number), not the column (letter)
```

With

```
Sheets(CurrentDistribution).Range("A4:" + LastCellCurrentDistribution).Copy Sheets("distribution1").Range("A" + CStr(LastRowInDistribution1 + 1)) 'i only wany the row (number), not the column (letter)
```

Answer (score 1):

I Imagine that you need to declare the variables `LastCellCurrentDistribution` `LastCellDistribution1` `LastRowInDistribution1` as long due to integers not being able to handle values greater than 32,000.

Try declaring them like below:

```
Dim LastCellCurrentDistribution As Long
Dim LastCellDistribution1 As Long
Dim LastRowInDistribution1 As Long
```